# How to join multiple table using jpql query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working with `flight_management_system` where I have three entity `UserEntity`, `FlightEntity` and `BookEntity`. `UserEnity` is associated with `BookEntity` and `FlightEntity` is associated with `BookEntity`. While i am trying to run my project I got error in eclipse ide.

Error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: flightName of: com.flightbook.entity.FlightEntity
```

Here down is my code:

**Entity**

```
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @JsonBackReference("auth")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = AuthGroupEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auth_id")
    private AuthGroupEntity authGroupEntity;

    @JsonManagedReference("booking")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userEntity")
    private List<BookEntity> bookEntities;

}

public class FlightEntity {
    @Id
    private String flightId;

    private String flightname;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date scheduleDate;

    @JsonManagedReference("flight")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "flightEntity")
    private List<BookEntity> bookEntities;

}

public class BookEntity {
    @Id
    private String bookingId;

    private String pasengerName;
    private String status;

    @JsonBackReference("flight")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = FlightEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id")
    private FlightEntity flightEntity;

    @JsonBackReference("booking")
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity userEntity;

}
```

**Model**

```
public class BookingList {
    private String bookingId;
    private String pasengerName;
    private String status;
    private Date scheduleDate;
    private String flightName;

    public BookingList(String bookingId, String pasengerName, String status, Date scheduleDate, String flightName) {
        this.bookingId = bookingId;
        this.pasengerName = pasengerName;
        this.status = status;
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
        this.flightName = flightName;
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Query("SELECT new com.flightbook.model.BookingList(b.bookingId, b.pasengerName, b.status, f.scheduleDate, f.flightName) FROM BookEntity b JOIN b.flightEntity f JOIN b.userEntity u WHERE u.id = ?1")
    List<BookingList> getFlightBookingByUserId(Long user_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is `flightname` not `flightName` for FlightEntity